# CSV file with headers for office 365 migration

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, migration

I am using the CSV file with headers only template from microsoft to import multiple users in the migration wizard for Office 365 Exchange Online...however once populated and saved.

When i verify on the admin console...it says;

There are some problems with the file.
Make sure the file:
Uses commas as delimiters between the columns.
Has 15 columns.

Cant seem to fix it.

Comment: If you open the file in Notepad and check the number of , on each row, do some have more than 15? Could it be that one of the users has a , in their name?

Comment: Thanks R. Tried adding values to the latter part of the file i.e. address and its got further.

However now I am getting the following;

[{"Row number":8,"Errors":["Invalid domain name used in username. "]},{"Row number":18,"Errors":["Invalid domain name used in username. "]},{"Row number":30,"Errors":["Invalid domain name used in username. "]},{"Row number":8,"Errors":["Invalid domain name used in username. "]}

Comment: There will be a rogue , in one of the fields that's tripping it up for sure.

Comment: Yes!!! Space before the comma!!!! :) Amazing Richie....been staring at it for 30 minutes and bam! sorted.

Comment: You're most welcome.